# unable to open web project the two need to map to the same server location error

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.0

I am getting the following error when trying to open a vb .net 1.0 project using VS2002.

"Unable to open Web project 'ProjectName'. The file path 'FilePath' does not correspond to the URL 'ProjectURL'. The two need to map to the same server location. HTTP 404: Object Not Found."

I have tried ALL of the links that Google threw at me (on the first page) on searching on "unable to open web project the two need to map to the same server location" term.

I get this error when trying to open an existing vb.net 1.0 project and also when creating a new one.

Are there any other solutions around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging around, I was able to find a solution to this. Here is how to diagnose this issue:

1. Check the version number for your VS 2002 installation. It should be 7.0.9955. If it is any thing earlier than that, you need to upgrade.
2. Read this [MS KB 327283](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;327283) article.
3. Download and install service pack 1 for VS 2002 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c41d8159-b42f-4d06-a797-e510494976ee&displaylang=en).

Once you complete the above steps, your version number should be 7.0.9955. Now if you open up the project again, it should open without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the settings of IE?

Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> Lan settings -> check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses"